# Inequalities, when does the sign change here?

Tags: inequality, divisibility, problem-solving

I have encountered a problem with inequalities. I have been looking at examples provided by two websites which 'solve' inequalities, however when I try using my own method, the extremely simple 'addition, subtraction, multiply, divide', I end up with the wrong inequality sign.

What I have done is as follows:

$$\frac{x-3}{x+3} < 4$$
$$x-3 < 4(x+3)$$
$$x-3 < 4x+12$$
$$x < 4x+15$$
$$-3x < 15$$
$$3x > -15$$
$$x > -5$$

I have guessed that that problem is somewhere in the first 2 lines, embarrassingly, however I am unsure what I am doing wrong; the 'calculators' are telling me the answer is $x < -5$ or $x > -3$.

What am I doing wrong with my solution, to get the $x > -5$ the wrong way around? What is this other path I can take to find the $x > -3$?

It'd be preferred if I did not have to start using the 'table' to test all solutions, but if that is the only way, it's fine.

Comment: You need to deal with two cases: $x+3>0$ and $x+3<0$. Remember that when you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number the inequality sign must be "flipped."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem happens when you multiply both sides by $(x+3)$, which can be a negative number, in which case the inequalitites would be reversed.

You need to deal with two cases: x+3>0 and x+3<0.

You use $x+3>0$ (or $x>-3$) to get $x>-5$, combining both give $x>-3$, which is part of the right answer.

Now use $x+3<0$ (or $x<-3$), change the direction of inequality while multiplying on both sides, and get the other direction, $x<-5$. Combining $x<-3$ and $x<-5$ gives just $x<-5$.

Best of luck.

Comment: I considered that, but since _x_ is unknown, how should I know whether to reverse the sign or not?

Comment: You mean $x^2 - 9 < 4(x+3)^2$?

Comment: To anonymous voter: Why the negative vote?  :O

Comment: You can take 2 cases, once $(x+3)$ being positive, once negative.

Comment: @Destrotant to expound on Juanito's comment a bit, it's not about "whether to reverse the sign or not". It's "reverse the sign AND not reverse the sign". $x+3$ can be both negative and positive, depending on x. So you solve two equations - one where you treat $x+3$ as if it were negative and one where you treat $x+3$ as if it were positive. If the equation means $x+3$ can't be one of those, you'll encounter an issue later one. It's a bit like absolute value. $|x| = 3$ means $x=3$ or $x=-3$. You have to take both into account.

Comment: @Duncan You're wrong in that '$x+3$ can be both negative and positive'. Actually, $x+3$ can be either negative OR positive (so we can analyse each case separately), but NOT BOTH at the same time.

Comment: @Duncan said "x+3 can be both negative and positive, depending on x." I think he is quite correct in saying that. You are misinterpreting what he said.

Comment: @CiaPan Like Juanito said - the phrase "$x+3$ can be both negative and positive" doesn't mean it's both at the same time. Obviously it can't be both at the same time. Both are possibilities doesn't mean simultaneous.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is at the second line. If $(x+3)$ is negative, then you would need to switch the inequality there. So you have to consider two cases: first when $(x+3)$ is positive (i.e. $x \geq -3$) and when $(x+3)$ is negative (i.e. $x \leq -3$). The rest of your calculations were good

Answer (score 2):

When you want to solve such inequalities, the standard way is to check how they compare with zero. In example, you would have $$ \frac{x-3}{x+3}-4<0$$ and thus $$\frac{-3x-15}{x+3}<0$$ You will have to use that table as you said, but it is the safest way to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply both sides by $(x+3)$ if $x < -3$, this value will be negative, and you will reverse the inequality.

The correct method is to multiply by $(x+3)^2$ which is always positive, and then solve the resulting $$(x-3)(x+3) <4(x+3)^2$$as a quadratic inequality.